# How to authenticate Google Sheets API using OAuth 2.0 from Postman/PowerAutomate(MS Flow)?

Tags: google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am new to Google Suit. As part of a requirement, we are trying to access Google Sheets from Microsoft Flows (Power Automate) using HTTP call. I have the details to access Google Sheets API such as client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri. It would be if any thoughts on the approach to achieve the authentication with the above details.

Scenario: We have some Google Sheets which holds data to be READ and WRITE Back.

I have tried calling Google Token API with below details, but getting an error

> Error 400: invalid_request
> Required parameter is missing: response_type

Our main goal is to bypass user consent and authenticate Google APIs using client id and secret and perform the required actions on the data.

Steps performed to authenticate the Google API

```
Method: Get
URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
Headers:
    {
      "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx0r0e4oe1dllujkiejtm7ii42jqk.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "redirect_uri": "https://console.cloud.google.com",
      "response_type": "code",
      "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
      "access_type": "offline",
      "prompt": "none"
    }
```

I am following https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest as a reference.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: @DaImTo please let me know in case of more details require helps for better reach, Thank you

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code actually generating this GET request? The error says that the `redirect_uri` is missing, but it's included in your list, though the list says "Headers", but these are supposed to be URL parameters. You can see how the URL should look in the Google [sample documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_2). Also, can you explain why you set the `redirect_uri` to the Google console? That address is supposed to lead to your app which will handle the response.

Comment: @Daniel that makes sense. But, as I am trying to call the API from https://flow.microsoft.com, actually I was using the same as redirect_uri, but still getting an error

Error 400: invalid_request

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.

Request Details
The content in this section has been provided by the app developer. This content has not been reviewed or verified by Google.
redirect_uri: https://flow.microsoft.com

Not sure were I am missing it

Comment: just to add another point, I tried passing the params are being passed as part of URL too, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting the request wrong.   The first call is a http get you just place it in a browser window

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope={scopes comma separated}&response_type=code
```

It will display the consent screen to the user.   All parameters form a query string. They are not sent as headers there is nothing in the docs that says it should be sent as headers.

[image]

Useful links:

- [Google 3 Legged OAuth2 Flow](https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)
- [Understanding Google OAuth 2.0 with curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w&t=4s)
- [The Discovery document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect?hl=en#discovery)